# How do I remove a natural resource on a tile?

Tags: reus

How can I cleanly remove a natural resource on a tile to micromanage a village's resources in *Reus*?  I know I can simply replace it by dropping something else there, but sometimes I want to simply remove that Animal, Vegetable, or Mineral.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Forest Giant](http://wiki.reusgame.com/index.php?title=The_Forest_Giant)'s Migrate ability to move natural resources from one place to another.

This ability requires the swamp ambassador.

Note that you cannot move a natural resource to a non-native biome.

Answer (score 0):

You can also damage the resources with your giants the same way you can damage a town or a building or an army. This will result in the resource being removed when it 'dies'.